# Not understanding this F# array issue

Tags: f#

I want to enumerate an enum:

```
type T =
| Type1 = 0
| Type2 = 1

let a = Enum.GetValues(typeof<T>)
```

which gives me this:

> val a : Array = [|T1; T2|]

now, I want to go through the array:

```
a |> Array.iter (fun x -> ())
```

but I get that:

> Type mismatch. Expecting a
>      'Array -> 'a'
>   but given a
>      ''b [] -> unit'
>   The type 'Array' does not match the type ''a []'

I don't understand why I have an array that doesn't match the array type...

Comment: `Enum.GetValues` is a bit funky, in the sense that it returns an `Array` and not a `T[]` or an `object[]`. Did you try casting it explicitly to `T[]`?

Comment: Lee's answer is to cast, like you suggested. Is there any document explaining why the .net types and F# types are kind of the same but ... not the same? I'm new in F# and maybe it's my lack of understanding, but it seems very messy and half baked at times compared to C# specifically because of this kind of issues. So I'm trying to understand the rational behind it bit also if this is a forever problem or things will eventually be merged.

Comment: F# and C# array types are the same and you'd get the same issue in C# trying to use for example `a.Select(_ => 1)` without casting.

Comment: so, what is the difference between the System.Array and the T[]? I don't get it

Comment: Agreed, maybe its good to add that `Array` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array?view=netframework-4.8) is a base type of `T[]`. It indicates an array of 'something', of no specific type. Now its mostly there for legacy reasons (Enum.GetValues was added .NET in or before 1.1, way before generics existed) and for it's methods. `Enum.GetValues<T>` returning a `T[]` would be neat, but they never added that. So the cast is up to the user. You don't need `Array` a lot in practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Enum.GetValues` returns a `System.Array` but `Array.iter` requires a generic array type. You can cast the value returned from `GetValues`:

```
let a = Enum.GetValues(typeof<T>) :?> T array
a |> Array.iter (fun x -> ())
```

Comment: I think you should cast it to `int array` not `T array`.

Comment: @ScottHutchinson - Why? Casting to `int array` loses type information.

Comment: `GetValues` returns the constant values, which are just some kind of ints. How else could you do something like `Array.iter (fun e -> printfn "Enumerator value: %d" e)`?

Comment: @ScottHutchinson - If you keep them as `T` values then you can convert to `int` whenever you need e.g. `a |> Array.iter (fun e -> printfn "Enumerator value: %d" (int e))`. Casting to `int array` now means you have to downcast to `T` whenever you need to treat it as an enum e.g. `a.[0] = T.Type1` won't typecheck.

Comment: I guess you're right. Though I think much of the time what we want is an int array, in which case we might as well cast it to that. The documentation makes a lot of us think that the return value is an array of the underlying type (e.g., int): "An array that contains the values of the constants in enumType." Hence my confusion.